# Range of an inverse sine trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, inverse-function

I am supposed to find the range of the function:
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{\sin^{-1}x}$$

**My approach:**
$$
\frac{-\pi }{2}\leq \sin^{-1}x\leq \frac{\pi }{2}$$
$$\frac{-2 }{\pi }\geq \frac{1}{\sin^{-1}x}\geq \frac{2}{\pi }$$
Going on solving further in a similar way, I'm getting the range as :
$$\left[\frac{-4}{\pi },\frac{4}{\pi }\right]-{0}$$
But the correct answer is supposed to be:
$$(-\infty , \frac{-4}{\pi }]\cup [\frac{-4}{\pi },\infty)$$
I would grateful if someone would point out the flaw in my approach.

Comment: What if $x=0$...? Also $-1<2$, does this imply $-1>1/2$?

Comment: Throw away the math for a moment, consider that $\sin^{-1}(x) = 0$ is out of bounds, because $\sin^{-1}(x)$ appears in the denominator of the expression, and ask yourself: what happens as the denominator approaches $0$ from the positive side?  As the denominator gets smaller and smaller, on the positive side, the expression **must grow unbounded**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you took reciprocals of the inequality
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\sin^{-1}(x)\leq\frac{\pi}{2} \, .
$$
In general, if $a<b$, then it is not necessarily true that
$$
\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{b} \, .
$$
Sometimes it is true, e.g. if $a=-2$ and $b=5$. Sometimes it is not true, e.g. if $a=4$ and $b=5$. It's a mistake to assume that you can always apply the same 'rules' to inequalities as you can equations.

Anyway, there is a simpler method you can take to solve this problem:

1. Plot the graph of $\sin(x)$ for $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.
2. Reflect the graph in the line $y=x$ to get the graph of $\sin^{-1}(x)$.
3. Use this to plot the graph of $\dfrac{1}{\sin^{-1}(x)}$.
4. Then plot $\dfrac{2}{\sin^{-1}(x)}$.

Pay particular attention to what happens when $x$ is close to $0$.